# Why assigning an object to another variable changing the initial object as well in Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am trying to do -

```
var a = {key1: "Value1", key2: "Value2"};
var b = a;
b.key3 = "Value3";
```

Though I was expecting `a` to console only `{key1: "Value1", key2: "Value2"}`

but if I do `console.log(a)` following is the result -

`{key1: "Value1", key2: "Value2", key3: "Value3"}`

For the time being I managed to make it work using `ES6` `Object.assign` method like -

```
var a = {key1: "Value1", key2: "Value2"};
var b = Object.assign({}, a);
b.key3 = "Value3";
console.log(a); // {key1: "Value1", key2: "Value2"}
```

But I am interested to know about the cause of this in JavaScript.

FYI - I tried to search/google but unable to find as I don't know about the exact phase to follow.

Comment: Objects are not copied, only referenced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing `var b = a;` it just makes another reference to the same object, which is accessible through both a and b.

The Object.assign() method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one (or more) object to another object.

```
var o1 = { a: 1 };
var o2 = { b: 2 };
var o3 = { c: 3 };

var obj = Object.assign(o1, o2, o3);
console.log(obj); // { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
console.log(o1);  // { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }, target object itself is changed.
```